# IIS6 redirect problems, please help?

Tags: iis-6, redirect

I have a main site, lets call it www.domain.com

I have a subdomain sub.domain.com

In my root directory, it has the "sub" folder. Inside "sub" folder, i have certain files that are not allowed to be viewed by public. So, in my IIS6 config, I set when public access the file, it would do a redirection to another URL. My problem is:

When I type this:

www.domain.com/sub/file  => It would redirect, but when I type this:

sub.domain.com/file      => It can access the file

The file type is .SWF

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though sub.domain.com has its own web site entry in IIS.  If that is the case, you will also need to alter the properties for that web site to restrict access (disable anonymous users, set IP restrictions, or however you're restricting access).  Alternatively, you could use NTFS permissions on the actual folder itself on the server to disallow the IUSR_MACHINENAME account from being able to list/read the files and it will cause IIS to prompt the user for credentials.